# Some old random orders are associated to newly registered customer Magento 2.3.5-p2

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p2

I have a problem about customer's orders. When new customer registers there is a chance that some random order will be attached to it. If I go to customer's orders I can see that they got orders which they never ordered. Do you have any solution? thank you in advance.

edit*
this is the error I'm getting if I press edit order:

[image: this is the error I'm getting]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the problem is known by Magento.

The problem was in the file: app/code/Magento/Persistent/Model/QuoteManager.php

It has been corrected in 2.3.4-p2.

But otherwise, the bug was a bit "random".

Here is the conversation around the bug: Issue 23618.

Otherwise, You can fix orphelin adresse by doing this :

> UPDATE quote_address SET customer_address_id=NULL WHERE
> customer_address_id NOT IN ( SELECT entity_id FROM
> customer_address_entity WHERE parent_id = quote_address.customer_id )